# Why can I pass incompatible functions into different function types?

Tags: typescript

I've noticed that TS function types aren't as strict as I wish they could be, even with the [`strictFunctionTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes) flag. In the code below you can see two numbered scenarios where I am able to pass in functions that aren't really compatible with the expected function types, which ultimately results in a runtime error. Any insights?

```
type FooCallback = (param: boolean) => void;

const fooCaller = (foo: FooCallback) => {
    foo(true);
};

type BarCallback = () => void;

const bartoFooPasser = (bar: BarCallback) => {
    // 1. Why no TS error?! FooCallback expects a boolean param but BarCallback doesn't define it!
    fooCaller(bar);
};

type Baz = {
    param: {
        subparam: string;
    };
};

// This gives a TS error as expected.
// const bar: BarCallback = (param: string) => {};

// 2. Why no TS error?! BarCallback expects no params, but this passes _purely_ because obj has a default??? Why?!
const barImplementer: BarCallback = (obj: Baz = { param: { subparam: '' }}) => {
    console.log(`The length of the string is ${obj.param.subparam.length}.`);
}; 

// This results in a runtime error :-/
bartoFooPasser(barImplementer);
```

You can play with this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAwgQwDaoEbIMYGsoC8UAFGMgE7IC2AXFBgqhMgHYCUhAfFAG5wCWAEwDcAKFHY4LAM7AoAMwQp0EcoRKK4deEjSYcuDgW4BvUVAsKExYOQCuENmIC+Y0aEhQAQhWX686sRG3HxCbpIycljkwHA6AArI0tKqgdF0PuR+WHjBUGaWUAD0RVAAjAB0UADqABYgUCxwUAAqAMpQquRw5AD8AISwSno5+BAAHpDYwNJQyPSMzCxQZJRU9HZymdkGUIJwENIsAORyghDy-CzQ-MD95paafqrE0U6iruIe0D4AXuoFSyrah0QGFCzSOwYYG0KCychXADmYkKn0+ohKrVq-FmiP4PEOc1aHS6PTmswmU2AEEEFQxpQisnoFAyvhGuyIpAoILhtiReRM6MxACYqnUGk1iZ1yN0+oNtuyApSINNZpKYdIADQbOTAbGzMjJQkAfTAdnIEFQIGN9BVyDsKSgcAwACsoLUkkTzvJ7ahgL0AzV6gMJFImdEAJJUMBMKgQFjU8isrKK-Cc50u1n-IgmFbc2G5yHQ-N0Y7HKDOZwCh4WRlwJgVVBwRHEAAGLVq0CYLEReqd8igeug8KRUBxUAAJCYMxUYRUi3Pu73as4Kq33q4oOJMR3xxbIX7ZlcifYE-w49LZVAaABaIqiaKxBJJFLkV4UKMxiBxhOqJxAA).

Comment: [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing the post to ask exactly one question and not multiple related ones; are you asking primarily about scenario 1 or scenario 2?

Comment: @jcalz Hmm, I'm struggling with rewording because I'm more-so trying to ask about the problem that arises when _both_ these scenarios are paired together, and how TS is letting me do things that it thinks are "safe" when in reality it leads to a runtime error. I'll think about this more though.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks! That explains scenario 1, but I'm more-so looking for a better way to get TS to prevent a runtime error with this fairly simple combination of scenarios.

Comment: It's a design limitation in TS, see [ms/TS#13043](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13043).  The unsafe thing is allowing optional parameters to be compatible with missing parameters (parameters, not arguments... we know optional parameters allow a missing *argument*) but it would be obnoxious to disallow it.  So it's a type hole you can fall into.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that seems to be the answer I'm looking for. If it's obnoxious to disallow it due to causing issues downstream because of how JS works, I still wish TS would provide an optional flag to make it work more like most other strongly typed languages out there and provide stronger type safety to devs who do want it regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a design limitation in TypeScript, see [microsoft/TypeScript#13043](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13043). There are some intentional [soundness](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness) holes in the language, whereby something potentially unsafe is allowed because it's very convenient.  One such hole involves [optional parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#optional-parameters) (and [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) also) where you're allowed to assign a function with an optional parameter with one that is *missing* that parameter:

```
let convenientButUnsafe: () => void = (x?: string) => x?.toUpperCase();
```

The reverse assignment is generally considered safe, where a function that requires a parameter is assignable to one that is missing that parameter, as mentioned [in the TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters):

```
let generallySafe: (x: number) => void = () => { }
```

Of course, in concert with the aforementioned type hole, this can lead to runtime errors.  The compiler is smart enough to prevent you from doing the bad assignment *directly*:

```
let nope: (x: number) => void = (x?: string) => x?.toUpperCase(); // compiler error!
```

But if you do it in multiple steps, the compiler will lose the information it needs to see the problem:

```
generallySafe = convenientButUnsafe; // uh oh
generallySafe(1); // runtime error
```

So that's what's happening.  Assignability in TypeScript isn't transitive.

---

One could imagine a more fully sound version of TypeScript in which the convenient but unsafe assignment would be an error, but that's not the direction the TypeScript team wants to take the language.  It is [not a TypeScript design goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) to be fully type safe at the expense of convenience.  Instead, the goal is to strike a balance between safety and ease of use.  The team has decided that there's nothing better to be done here.  Also note that commandline flags do not generally solve this problem; each such flag added doubles the number of possible compiler configurations, and trying to close every such hole is, in the words of the TS Team dev lead, ["a fool's errand"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825#issuecomment-306272034).  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9825](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9825) for a larger discussion about soundness or the lack thereof in TypeScript.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBsFMBcAIHNIDtICcCG5wE8DK6AzSALlgAoAPUpAVwFsAjNASlgF4A+WANwHsBLACbtyrTrADesAL4QYsAMa8k3ZP2TQAQjWgBVJAGdCJUey58hIygH5SB6Kn5J4YrhWsA6aL10AHX2gAwugGkGTMANygcnDQABb8BgDq-FgAoqiovKiklNT0TKiuPALCbOTudg5OLmaw7l4+-kEhYZHRIIgoGFh4xiJKKmoa2nqGxhGwAPRTsDRxsLxxoF1omDj4RGQAjJHTs6g0SND8dJCwaFmoHUA)